# how do i create a calculated field for this table?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT book.BookTitle, author.Name, author.Surname, book.YearofPublication
FROM book
    LEFT JOIN author ON book.AuthorID = author.AuthorID;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOOos.png)

This is my current table and I need to create a calculated field to tell me how many years the book has been published for but my brain is fried. Can anyone help?

I've tried using xaamp queries but don't see an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT book.BookTitle, author.Name, author.Surname, book.YearofPublication , YEAR(NOW()) - book.YearofPublication
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON book.AuthorID = author.AuthorID;
```

Comment: unfortunately not